# cannot create zfs pool on iscsi multipath drives

Tags: linux, zfs, iscsi

I have a disk on iSCSI SAN, which i have mounted on my server through multipath. when i run the command to create zfs pool using

```
zpool create -f zfs-data /dev/sdc
```

or

```
zpool create -f zfs-data /dev/sdd  (as the disk is mounted on both sdc and sdd)
```

i get error:

```
cannot open '/dev/sdc1': Device or resource busy
cannot create 'zfs-data': one or more vdevs refer to the same device, or one of
the devices is part of an active md or lvm device
```

The fdisk -l gives this output:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/eql-0-8a0906-f10764e0b-590d2ef939e523ac_b: 107.4 GB, 107379425280 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13003 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

                                                Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/eql-0-8a0906-f10764e0b-590d2ef939e523ac_bp1               1       13004   104862719+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/mapper/eql-0-8a0906-f10764e0b-590d2ef939e523ac-novaplesk'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

ZFS pool cannot be created on multipathed devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be getting sdc and sdd, but you need to work with the multipath device created over them.  What's your output for 'multipath -ll'?  e.g., I have four paths here:

```
dbslave2-mysql (36090a028c039386000104572042da1b0) dm-3 EQLOGIC,100E-00
size=550G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
|- 6:0:0:0 sdf 8:80 active ready running
|- 9:0:0:0 sde 8:64 active ready running
|- 8:0:0:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
`- 7:0:0:0 sdd 8:48 active ready running`
```

So I work with /dev/mapper/dbslave2-mysql, not with sdc, sdd, sde, or sdf.  In your case, it looks like you'd use /dev/mapper/eql-0-8a0906-f10764e0b-590d2ef939e523ac_b in your zpool creation commands.